# Pass a Map as argument to another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I just had an interview test in which I had to build a Route suggestion feature using ReactJS. Long story short, I tried to use the Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path between 2 train stations in a network.

In my implementation, I maintained a `tracingMap` which is a `Map` object that stores a station X as key. The value of this `Map` is another station Y which is a neighbor of X that is on the shortest path from the origin station to X. My goal is to recursive call `tracingMap.get(destStation)` while `destStation != origStation` in the end in order to rebuild the shortest path from the origin station to destination station.

The skeleton is as following:

```
// Store all the StationNode using stationId as key
let stationGraph = new Map();

function findShortestPath(origStationId, destStationId) {
   let tracingMap = new Map();

   ... perform the Dijkstra's algorithm ...

   return buildRoute(tracingMap, origStationId, destStationId);
}

function buildRoute(tracingMap, origStationId, destStationId) {
   ...
}
```

Here is my problem. I have a `StationNode` class which is my own custom object to implement the graph of stations. Initially, I tried to use this class as both `key` and `value` of my `tracingMap`. I tried to use `console.log(tracingMap)` at the end of the `findShortestPath()` function to make sure the map was updated properly and I could see all the entries I added just fine. I even tried to call `console.log(tracingMap.get(destStationNode))` to be 10000% sure that I can get the value I need.

However, when the `tracingMap` arrives at the `buildRoute()` function, `tracingMap.get(stationGraph.get(destStationId))` returns `undefined`. I couldn't get any values out of it even though `console.log(tracingMap)` is still showing that ALL entries are still there.

In the end, I had to change my implementation to stores `stationId` as `key` and `value` in the `tracingMap`. Then it would work just fine when I pass this `Map` to the other function.

As I'm relatively inexperienced in JavaScript, I'd be very grateful if you could tell me what I've done wrong. I believe I have a wrong understanding somewhere :).

Comment: Oh, understood your requirements, you have no logical issue, please try to make jsfiddle for your problem.https://jsfiddle.net/